# Enable logging internal openssl messages

Tags: c, ssl, logging, openssl

I'd like to get error messages during SSL handshakes to be printed or passed to my code from libssl/libcrypto.

I don't think the messages in msg_cb() from apps/s_cb.c in the openssl sources are enough. I'd like to see more than the message contents, I can see those using wireshark. I'm looking for errors such as "invalid HMAC", "unknown certificate", "certificate validation error", etc.

The calls to SSLErr is what I'm after. For example:

```
SSLerr(SSL_F_SSL23_GET_CLIENT_HELLO, SSL_R_UNSUPPORTED_PROTOCOL);
```

Comment: Are you looking for something like [ERR_print_errors()](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/crypto/ERR_print_errors.html)?

Comment: Guys, I am facing the same problem. Tried using ERR_print_errors() but it just prints all NULL values. Am I missing something ? I am building on Windows using Visual Studio. Appreciate your kind help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file `doc/ssleay.txt` in the OpenSSL source tree contains a big warning that it is obsolete. The section called `error.doc` still seems rather accurate though and gives a good overview of the different OpenSSL error mechanisms. You are not supposed to completely trust it.

The real documentation contains everything you need, but more scattered. The main entry point is the [man page about `err`](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/crypto/err.html) and the different links it points to.

One of them that seems useful for you is [`ERR_print_errors()`](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.0.2/man3/ERR_print_errors.html) for v1.0.2. Replace the version number with your version of interest.